# Not able to understand what this error means

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDhlz.png)I am trying to create graphql schema directive and trying to add it in makeExecutableSchema and the following error is occurring. Is there anyone who can help me understand this error or solve it.

```
const templateDirective = require('../index');

// Define your schema and resolvers if needed

const typeDefs = `
  type Query {
    me(): Me @templateDirective
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    me: () => false,
  },
};

module.exports = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  schemaDirectives: {
    templateDirective,
  },
});
```

Comment: What error? Please update your question to include the full error message.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the screenshot of the error, I have edited the description

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your document. If a field takes no arguments, you have to omit the parentheses, you cannot just have an empty set of parentheses after the field name. The corrected document:

```
type Query {
  me: Me @templateDirective
}
```

Comment: ```const typeDefs = `
  type Query {
    me(id: Int): Me @directive
  }

  type Me {
    id: ID
  }
`;```
I added this and it worked. thanks